# Chrome Bug : User Profile, Under Activity Tab, Tool Tip Display Issue

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

[image: Tool tip on "people reached" link in the impact box of Activity Tab]

In chrome browser the tooltip is not displayed as expected when mouse is hovered over the people reached link in the impact box of activity tab of a user profile.
while I checked this on Microsoft edge browser the text was visible but the tool tip has slightly cropped from the top.

Comment: Reproducible on Chrome 58.0.3

Comment: I don't see this, but then again I have disabled the floating top-bar.

Comment: The version of my chrome is 58.0.3029.110 on which i get this issue.